# Control the pod domain

Tags: kubernetes

I have *pod1* and *pod2* in the same namespace.

*pod2* is running an HTTP server.

How can I easily get pod2 be seen as `pod2.mydomain.com` from pod1?

In this way the HTTPS certificate would work with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved through the kubernetes cluster and it is important to use a valid SSL certificate.

By using a Kubernetes service you can create  a service of type “ClusterIP” or “NodePort” in the same namespace as the pods and you need to expose the pod2 HTTP server to a consistent IP and port. In this way you can configure your DNS to map pod2.mydomain.com to the IP address of the service.

Or if your cluster supports load balancing you can create a Service of type “LoadBalancer” and you can expose pod2 HTTP server to a public IP.
You can also create an Ingress service that routes traffic to pod 2 on the hostname.
For more information please check this official [Document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly hit the **POD** with it's **IP** fine how you are thinking however it would better to use the **service** with **POD**.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: proxy
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:stable
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
        name: http-web-svc

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-1
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: proxy
  ports:
  - name: name-of-service-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: http-web-svc
```

Service route the traffic to matching labels PODs, so from POD1 you hit the request to service-1 which will forward traffic to **POD-1** and response.

```
https://service-1.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local
```

with service **HTTPS** will also work the way you asked. Test with the **curl** command, start one **curl** pod

```
kubectl run mycurlpod --image=curlimages/curl -i --tty -- sh
```

hit **curl** request to service

```
curl https://service-1.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local
```

service ref doc : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service

**Extra** :

You can also use the **ingress & service mesh** which will make little simple for you scenario if you don't want to manage **SSL/TLS** cert for the app.

**Service mesh** supports the **mTLS** **auth** you can force policy and it would be easy however there will be extra management.

Comment: So, I have to use `service-1.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local` instead of `mydomain.com`

Comment: if you wan to internally call yes else using domain it request will go outside to public resolve the domain and come back to cluster unless you have internal DNS mapping where you are managing the domain mapping. otherwise, best practice is to use the service-name for internal communication service to service.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to change SSL certificates, and to use a specific domain, here is the technique I've used successfully:

- install the `sudo` utility
- Run this instruction in the `pod1`'s `Dockerfile`, supposing that the user is `myuser`:

```
   echo 'myuser   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/chmod 666 /etc/hosts' > /etc/sudoers.d/chmod;
```

- At runtime, from `pod1` calculate the IP of `pod2` by running:

```
kubectl get pod pod2 --template {{.status.podIP}}
```

- Then run:

```
sudo chmod 666 /etc/hosts
```

- Then add the following line in `/etc/hosts` (changing `ip` by the real IP):

```
ip pod2.mydomain.com
```

Maybe this solution is not the most Kubernetes-ish, but it avoids me to deal with certificates.

I consider changing `/etc/hosts` by far easier than to play with self signed cerficates and all this kind of stuff.

Comment: didn't get what you are planning to do will check once get free however for quick ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/

Comment: I only know the IP at runtime, so I have to modfify `/etc/hosts` on the fly.  In my case `pod1` is created before than `pod2`.

Comment: just courious any reason not using the service ?

Comment: because the service doesn't allow me to use *any* domain I wish.

Comment: you can map service and domain in DNS, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/ that would be more scalable option also if anytime deployment get scale of poD get updated or anything happen to pod IP might get change.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable tip @HarshManvar. In my case it is just for automated testing purposes, and pods are short lived.  I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: sure, no issues, anytime :) always happy to learn & curious..!